# Operand evaluation order and associativity

Tags: operator-precedence

I'm having trouble figuring out the difference between the two. Say you have these givens:

```
a[0] = 10
a[1] = 13
a[2] = 17
a[3] = 19
x = 0
y = 3
```

OPERATOR PRECEDENCE:

```
++, --  
*, /, % Left Associative  
+, - Left Associative
```

OPERAND EVALUATION ORDER:
Right to Left

Given the rules above, how would I evaluate the expression below?

```
a[++x] + ++x % 7 % y
```

According to my professor, the answer is 18, but I cannot figure out why. From what I understand associativity is the order same precedence operators are evaluated and operand evaluation order is the order operands get evaluated so something like 2 % 7 would be 2 with left to right operand evaluation order and 1 with operation evaluation order. Can anyone explain how my professor got the answer of 18?

Answer (score 2):

The precedence and associativity tell you how the expression is (implicitly) parenthesised. The evaluation order then determines in which order the subexpressions are  evaluated.

Let us look at the example:

```
a[++x] + ++x % 7 % y
```

On the top level, there are `+` and `%` as operators. `+` has lower precedence, so that's

```
a[++x] + (++x % 7 % y)
```

The right subexpression has two `%`, and that is left associative, hence

```
a[++x] + ((++x % 7) % y)
```

Now with right-to-left evaluation order, `((++x % 7) % y)` is evaluated first. Again with right-to-left evaluation order, `y` is evaluated first, resulting in 3. Then `++x % 7` is evaluated. First 7, then `++x`. The latter results in 1. So that's `1 % 7 = 1`. I'll leave the rest to you, since it's homework.

Comment: It was a question that I got wrong on an old test that he have us the answers to that I'm studying off of for the final, bad tag I guess. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have `() + () % 7 % y`. Based on the rules, `() % 7` is evaluated before `... % y` and that before `() + ...`.

In `++x % 7` you first evaluate `++x` and get 1 and `x=1`. `1 % 7 = 1`.
Then you do `1 % y` or `1 % 3` and get 1.
Now you do `a[++x] + 1`. Remembering that `x=1`, you get `a[2] + 1 = 17 + 1 = 18`.